# Check whether Azure SQL database has been fully removed

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-functions

I am creating a simple Azure logic app that uses a function to:

1. Delete a slave database
2. Restore a copy of a master database (with the same name as the removed slave)

**Remove Database**

```
# Remove slave database
Remove-AzSqlDatabase `
    -DatabaseName $RestoreDatabaseName `
    -ServerName $ServerName `
    -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName

Write-Host "Removed slave database"
```

**Restore PIT Backup of Master**

```
# Restore database
Restore-AzSqlDatabase `
      -FromPointInTimeBackup `
      -PointInTime (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-2) `
      -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName `
      -ServerName $ServerName `
      -TargetDatabaseName $RestoreDatabaseName `
      -ResourceId $Database.ResourceID `
      -ElasticPoolName $ElasticPoolName
```

The issue i am having is that after removing the database, Azure still sees the database on the server and so i get the following error when restoring:

> The destination database name 'Slave' already exists on the server
>   'server address'.

I cant find any way to check if this has been fully removed before starting the next function. Any help on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Get-AzSqlDatabase](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.sql/get-azsqldatabase?view=azps-3.3.0) to check if the DB is still in play.

```
Get-AzSqlDatabase -ResourceGroupName "ResourceGroup01" -ServerName "Server01" -DatabaseName "Database02"
```

Placing this in a loop with a sleep will give you a poll to check when the DB is finally gone for good and you can then resume your processing.

```
Start-Sleep -s 15
```

Make sure you have a circuit breaker in your logic to prevent and endless loop in the case of a failed deletion.

It may be easier to restore your DB with a new name to avoid the delay `e.g. MyDb<yyyymmdd>`

Or alternatively, use the [Azure REST API from SQL DB delete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/sql/databases/delete#examples).

```
DELETE https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/00000000-1111-2222-3333-444444444444/resourceGroups/Default-SQL-SouthEastAsia/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/testsvr/databases/testdb?api-version=2017-10-01-preview
```

and [monitor the location response of the 204 Accepted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/async-operations) to determine when the database has been completely removed. [Azure Durable Functions give you a great monitor pattern you can use](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-overview?tabs=csharp).

Comment: Unfortunately this does not seem to work in the Azure function, the loop errors with a not found error, then immediately returns an already exists error when trying to restore. You are probably correct though, maybe i should restore and then rename after.

Comment: I have added another option to the answer if you are comfortable with REST API's. Use the delete SQL DB REST API, it should return a 204 Accepted, then use the location returned in the 204 response to poll until the DB is fully deleted. A durable function using a monitor pattern would be ideal. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-overview?tabs=csharp

Comment: Thanks, will give the REST API a try. Unfortunately durable functions don't support PowerShell or Python so i would be a bit lost there.